# C++ .length() function giving wrong results

Tags: c++, string

My code that analyzes a string is printing incorrect number of positions in integers.
The result is initially off by 1 integer, and when I insert a char to the string, the result changes by 2 position values even though I only added one char. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s1 = "Hey, what's up?";
    cout << s1.length() << endl; // should be 14 positions, not 15 if starting at 0
    cout << s1.insert(1, "k") << endl;
    s1 = s1.insert(1, "k");
     cout << s1.length() << endl; //should be 15, not 17
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me why `.length()` is not printing the correct number of positions.

Comment: "if starting at 0"? `length()` gives you the length, not the index of the last position. And the phrase it does have 15 characters length.

Comment: Umm, I count 15 chars in "Hey, what's up?".  So, the length is 15.  What's the problem then?  Length is not a position.

Comment: pro programmer tip. 99 times out of 100, it is not the libraries fault

Comment: Sorry,the first part is correct; but the second issue is still valid when the position printed is 17 and not 16.

Comment: You say it should be 15 in the code. Why 15 or 16 and not 17?

Comment: @user2877144 you call `s1.insert(1, "k")` twice, `insert` mutates the string it's called on

Comment: I have added to my answer to cover the rest of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.length()` does not return the end position of the string, it returns the number of elements in the string. ie. "four" will be 4 because it has four letters.

```
std::string four = "four";
std::cout << four.length() << std::endl;
```

output:

```
4
```

The reason that the return for the second part is 17 and not 16, is because you insert k twice, once in your std::cout and a second time later in the code. Your actual output string will be this:

```
Hkkey, what's up?
```

Answer (score 3):

`string::length()` returns the number of characters in the string, not the position of the last character, so `15` is correct.

Think about this: what would an empty string return if `length()` returns the position of the last character like you think?

Answer (score 2):

`string::length` returns the number of characters, which is **not** the same as the number of positions.  The number of characters is the quantity that you would count out if you started at the start and incremented a counter for each character, so it shouldn't come out to the index of the last position.  The range of valid indices is `[0, str.length() - 1]`, which includes `str.length()` positions.

Hope this helps!